# How would you test something with complex output?

Tags: junit

I wrote a parser for a non-trivial language this weekend.  Some of the output can be complex, even for seemingly simple input.  Let's say the input to the parser is a mathematical expression, and the output is a list of tuples that describe the input.

So the output could be 20 lines long.

How would you write the junit test?  Would you run the parser, hand-check the result, and if it seems correct, drop the result into the unit test as the Right Answer?

Or is this just insane, and I need to do something differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally the idea of a "unit" test is that it tests a small unit of functionality.  If the output is so complex that it's difficult to test, that implies that you're testing too large a unit of functionality.

Remember that in addition to verifying that your code works, your unit tests can also act as an example of how your code should be used.  A single test that just matches a result against a large predefined result probably won't do that.

Try to break the inner workings into smaller methods and test each one.  Try to test building up a result from smaller results (e.g. if input A results in output Y, and input B results in output Z, then write a test for whether input AB results in output YZ, or whatever the appropriate result would be).

Comment: The parser is recursive descent.  So if parse() calls a() b() and c(), you're recommending that I instead prefer to unit test those methods, or what they invoke etc etc.  I'm down with that.  But what then would be a higher level of testing, where I am certainly testing the public interfaces?

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfectly valid test, but not necessarily a unit test. This is tending towards being an integration test or regression test:

> How would you write the junit test? Would you run the parser,
>   hand-check the result, and if it seems correct, drop the result into
>   the unit test as the Right Answer?

It's perfectly valid to use JUnit to do your integration tests and/or regression tests. I use the approach you've described a lot of the time, but you need to be aware that this has limitations.

1. Unless you're careful, your tests end up being quite brittle. For instance, your output could contain unexpected characters (spaces, cr/lf and encoding is a particular problem if you're mixing unix and windows machines). This makes the testing slightly more complex because you have to "clean" the output of your parser.
2. It's a pain to have 20 lines of text in your junit java class, along with the input. So you're faced with the choice of having the text in the java, of putting them into a separate file. Most of the time, I find separate files easier to manage, and the methods are a single line which takes a file, processes it and compares it against a reference file.
3. Because you're doing integration tests, it'd harder to identify the cause when you have a failing test.

As JacobM says, it's probably a good idea to split down your tests down to smaller pieces, but you can leave the other tests, because they're useful as well.